# Proving convergence of sums: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b^2_n$ converge then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b^2_n$ prove that: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges.

I thought about this answer:
In order for a sum to converge i has to be bounded, Means Let $M_1\epsilon R$, So that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<M_1 $.
Same goes for $b_n$. [And lets say $M_2$].

So is it just: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\le \max(M_1*M_2, \sqrt{M_1*M_2}$)?

And one more question:
Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_n$ prove that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

If i go the same as before, I have hard time cause i get something like:  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{M_1 }{n}$ which doesn't converge [I think].

Any guidelines please?

Comment: See also: [$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2$ converge show $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n$ converges absolutely](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557206) and [Sum of the squares of a sequences converge, does the product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2579185)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Every time squares are involved, think about Cauchy Schwarz inequality.
Just show that the partial sum of absolute value are bounded.

I'll help you with the first step :

$$\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k b_k|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |b_k|^2}$$

Comment: How 'bout the second one?

Comment: What do you think about : $b_n=1/n$ ?

Comment: Oh thanks......

Answer (score 4):

Use this inequality

$$|a_nb_n|\leq \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't work for complex numbers, does it ? (I mean you get complex conjugates at some points?)

Comment: Yes but it works if the series $\sum_n a_n^2$ and $\sum_n b_n^2$ are absolutely convergent.

Comment: Oh yes right ! Thanks