# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2$ converge show $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n$ converges absolutely

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2$ converge. Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n$ converges absolutely.

My idea so far:

- It's quite quite obvious that both given series converge absolutely
- So the Cauchy-Produc tells me that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 b_n^2 = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n b_n)^2$ converges absolutely

I got stuck at that point. Can somehow give me a hint how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you call this [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) ? The way you wrote it is much simpler.

Comment: From $(a-b)^2\ge 0$, one deduces $ab\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$. You could use this and the Comparison Test.

Comment: Mirko is is absolutely right, Cauchy product was reserved for something else, don't use it arbitrarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
0 & \le (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \\
0 & \le (a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \\[10pt]
\text{Therefore} \\
-2ab & \le a^2+b^2, \\
2ab & \le a^2 + b^2, \\[10pt]
\text{and consequently} \\
2|ab| & \le a^2 + b^2.
\end{align}

So
$$
\sum_n |a_n b_n| \le \frac 1 2 \left( \sum_n a_n^2 + \sum_n b_n^2 \right) < \infty.
$$

Comment: Isn't the AM-GM inequality great?

Answer (score 3):

$\sum |a_n b_n|\le \sum b_n^2 + \sum a_n^2$

spoiler:

> if $|a_n|\le|b_n|$ then $|a_n\cdot b_n|\le b_n^2$ else $|a_n\cdot b_n|\le a_n^2$, so $\sum |a_n b_n|\le \sum b_n^2 + \sum a_n^2$

Edit: Second spoiler (complete solution with all details):

> if $|a_n|\le|b_n|$ then $|a_n\cdot b_n|\le b_n^2\le b_n^2+a_n^2$ else $|a_n\cdot b_n|\le a_n^2\le a_n^2+b_n^2$. In all cases $|a_n\cdot b_n|\le b_n^2+a_n^2$ so $\sum |a_n b_n|\le \sum (b_n^2 + a_n^2)=\sum b_n^2 + \sum a_n^2<\infty$.

Comment: I will up-vote this if you add what you earlier said in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks

Comment: @Dr.MV I added a second spoiler with all details to avoid any misinterpretation

Comment: @Mirko Yes!  That is better!!!  Well done!

Comment: @Mirko No worry.  I hadn't read your added spoiler.  So, apology.  I hope your class went well and you enjoy teaching.  - Mark

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

From Cauchy-Schwarz we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|a_n\, b_n\right|\le\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n^2\right)\,\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n^2\right)}$$